# CSS Roll-over link not working to well

Tags: css

I have a roll-over link I saw on this page: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/11/40-essential-wordpress-plugins/ (see rollover links: Jetpack, Jetpack lite, sociable etc)
but I cannot get it to work:

HTML:

```
<a class="roll-link"><span>This is a link</span></a>

.roll-link span {
   display: block;
   color: #DD4D42;
   position: relative;
   padding: 0 2px;
   -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
   -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
   -ms-transition: all 400ms ease;
   transition: all 400ms ease;
   -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
   -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
   -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
   transform-origin: 50% 0%;
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

See my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CNSWn/6/)

```
.roll-link:hover span {
   background: #DD4D42;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
   -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
   -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
   transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
}
```

Comment: want you want to do to this, on mouseover the links hided and on mouseout is shows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing some of the styles, including those for the base `.roll-link` element and for the `.roll-link:after`, which displays the content of the link. Here's a jsFiddle with the working effect: http://jsfiddle.net/CNSWn/7/

This is a pretty clever effect and it's worth spending some time to study the way they've used the `data-title` attribute to show the second 'side' of the link on hover.

Comment: Also, this does not work FTM in browsers which does not support 3d transform on pseudo elements, such as Chrome. Workaround is to clearly specify a div in addition to the span in the link, at the expense of markup quality. Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HkeAy/

Comment: Is this possible without the Span tag?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

**HTML:**

```
<a class="roll-link external"><span data-title="Jetpack">Jetpack</span></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #dd4d42;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.roll-link {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: top;
    -webkit-perspective: 600px;
    -moz-perspective: 600px;
    -ms-perspective: 600px;
    perspective: 600px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    perspective-origin: 50% 50%;     
}

.roll-link span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 2px;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 400ms ease;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.roll-link:hover span {
    background: #DD4D42;    
    -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
    -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
    -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
    transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
}

.roll-link span:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 2px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #DD4D42;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
    -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
    -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
    transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/pR4sg/